# Remove Key Value Pair in Foreach Loop in List

Tags: c#, key-value

I want to remove a key-value pair from List after displaying it 
But it gives me error message like [ Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. exception]

Here is code

```
if (senderRemainingSeqList.Count > 0)
{
      senderRemainingSeqList.Sort();

      foreach (var row in senderRemainingSeqList)
      {
          if ( row.Key == currentSenderID)
          {
               if (row.Value == senderNextSeqList[currentSenderID])
               {
                 Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",row.Key,row.Value);
                  senderRemainingSeqList.Remove(row);
               }
         }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the collection you are enumerating on, instead you can filter out values not matching your criteria and the create a new list using `ToList` and assign it back to your `senderRemainingSeqList`:

```
senderRemainingSeqList = senderRemainingSeqList
                .Where(row=> row.Key != currentSenderID && 
                 row.Value != senderNextSeqList[currentSenderID])
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop on *copy* of the initial list, and so you're allowed to modify it:

```
  ...
  // Note ToList(); 
  foreach (var row in senderRemainingSeqList.ToList()) {
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Comment: That's actually quite smart, never thought of it!

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop if you want to modify the collection or create a RemoveList during enumeration and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a reverse loop to avoid mistakes while removing.

```
for(int i = list.Count -1; i >= 0; --i)
{ 
    // Determine if this is the pair you want to remove
    if(list[i].key == keyToRemove)
         list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

You have to do this backwards otherwise the list might change structure and entries might be skipped.